# Selenium test runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't work?

Tags: windows, selenium, webdriver, ordered-test

I'm working with Selenium in VB.NET using IEDriver. I want to launch my ordered tests suite on my windows server 2008 R2 (My server used IE 11). I launch my test by command line : vstest.console.exe.
When I launch this on Windows 7, that works. I try to launch it on my server ( OS : windows server 2008 R2). That launch my Internet Explorer and my first page test. My test fail on the first try to find element (text input) and send key . However the element is present on my web page and I launch on the same website. I don't know where is my problem. I have some idea :

- IE Driver compatibility with Windows Server 2008 R2 can't modify
- Security server, some rights don't allow my driver to interact with IE
- Problem in my code tests (Impossible for me, because the same code run perfectly on the same website)

Someone have any idea ?

Comment: You mean you can't modify any of the protected mode settings for IE in your machine? If this is the case, please contact your IT Admin - this directly hinders your ability to work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with windows server. Look for installed updates in server. This will probably occur because of that. Windows sometimes install updates without telling you and there are some updates that tamper with IEdriver and breakes it